# UIStepper does not move up when Navigation Bar dissapears

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I am writing a IPhone App. In it there is a search bar (UISearchBar with Controller). When I select it, it gets focussed, and the navigation bar disappears, and the body gets darkened so that when I type on search bar the suggestions (search results) appear. My problem is when I select the search bar, before I type anything, I can see my original view through a tinted black body area. There I see all of my other controls (buttons, textfields) moved up (because navigation bar disappeared), but the UISteppers have not moved, which makes them misaligned.

Why is this ?

[image: Before Search]

[image: After Search - 2 steppers misalinged]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on how you have the relative alignment setup. In your Storyboard, use the Inspector (the ruler icon on the right hand side options) and see if you have set the others to be relative.

Comment: Thank you It worked like magic. I just had to change the auto sizing settings in the ruler. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug.  I have noticed the same exact behavior in several apps I have worked on (both iPad and iPhone) Storyboard based apps.  I have re-produced this behavior on apps with only one orientation.  To re-produce, simply layout a scene and add UI elements of different types with at least one UIStepper.  Then add the scene to a Nav Controller and all the UI elements will move EXCEPT for any UISteppers.